# How do I write each sublist of a multidimensional in descending order?

Tags: python

```
input = [[3,2,4],[5,7,8],[9,1,4]]

output = [[4,3,2],[8,7,5],[9,4,1]]
```

I appreciate your help.  Is there a pythonic way of doing it?  Also I have numpy, so using numpy would be cool to see.

I have brainstormed and wanted to try and do it by writing each sublist as 1D lists followed by writing each sublist in descending order followed by re-introducing a multidimensional list.  How could you do this?  I am very mathematical, so it would be cool to see a very mathematical method of doing it?

Comment: this type of operation is called "sorting". You can find out some similar questions if you use that term explicitly, see if you can make an attempt at this problem on your own?

Comment: `output = [sorted(e, reverse=True) for e in input]`, as a side note don't use input as a variable name.

Comment: Pandas ;) but this one is for numpy

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
output=[sorted(sublist,reverse=True) for sublist in input]
print(output)
```

---

Output:

```
[[4, 3, 2], [8, 7, 5], [9, 4, 1]]
```

Comment: `key` is a kwarg for `sorted`, so that could be confusing

Answer (score 0):

Using `output = [sorted(l)[::-1] for l in input]]` is fastest in comparison to `output = [sorted(l, reverse=True) for l in input]`. I have provided proof as well.

```
In [4]: input = [[3,2,4],[5,7,8],[9,1,4]] 
   ...:  
   ...: output = [sorted(l)[::-1] for l in input]                                                                                                                        
In [5]: output                                                                                                        
Out[5]: [[4, 3, 2], [8, 7, 5], [9, 4, 1]]
```

#### `Proof` - which is fastest, `sorted(l, reverse=True)` OR `sorted(l)[::-1]`?

> **Note:** More details about `timeit` can be found at https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html

```
In [10]: from timeit import timeit                                                                                                                                          

In [11]: timeit("[sorted(l)[::-1] for l in [[3,2,4],[5,7,8],[9,1,4]] ]", number=1)    

Out[11]: 5.978000444883946e-06

In [12]: timeit("[sorted(l, reverse=True) for l in [[3,2,4],[5,7,8],[9,1,4]] ]", number=1)                                                                                                                  
Out[12]: 7.292000191227999e-06
```

And first way takes less time than 2nd one.

```
In [13]:  
In [33]: 5.978000444883946e-06 < 7.292000191227999e-06                                                                                                                                                      
Out[33]: True

In [34]:
```